# Merge values in object, if other value in the said object is the same

Tags: javascript, angular

For example, I have an array like this.

```
[{
    "Country": "USA",   "Nickname": "John"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Grace"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Mark"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Paul"
}, {
    "Country": "China", "Nickname": "Sansa"
}, {
    "Country": "USA",   "Nickname": "Clint"
}, {
    "Country": "China", "Nickname": "James"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Mary"
}]
```

I want my array to look like this..

```
[{
    "Country": "USA",   "Nickname": "John , Clint"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Grace , Mark , Paul , Mary"
}, {
    "Country": "China", "Nickname": "Sansa, James"
}]
```

I want to merge the nicknames by their country. What should I do?

Comment: You could start by making an attempt yourself and then posting the code here when (if) you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy example done by object and array.

Next time you can totally try it yourself, dude.

```js
var arr = [{
    "Country": "USA",   "Nickname": "John"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Grace"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Mark"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Paul"
}, {
    "Country": "China", "Nickname": "Sansa"
}, {
    "Country": "USA",   "Nickname": "Clint"
}, {
    "Country": "China", "Nickname": "James"
}, {
    "Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Mary"
}]

var obj = {};
var new_arr = [];

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  var d = arr[i];
  if(!obj[d['Country']])
    obj[d['Country']] = [];
  obj[d['Country']].push(d['Nickname']);  
}

for(var key in obj){
  new_arr.push({
    "Country": key,
    "Nickname": obj[key].join(' , ')
  })
}
console.log(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{"Country": "USA", "Nickname": "John"}, {"Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Grace"}, {"Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Mark"}, {"Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Paul"}, {"Country": "China", "Nickname": "Sansa"}, {"Country": "USA",   "Nickname": "Clint"}, {"Country": "China", "Nickname": "James"}, {"Country": "Japan", "Nickname": "Mary"}];

let answer = [];
arr.forEach(x=>{
  if(!answer.some(y => y.Country === x.Country)){
    answer.push(x);
  }else{
    let country = answer.find(y => y.Country === x.Country);
    country.Nickname = country.Nickname.concat(`, ${x.Nickname}`);
  }
});

console.log(answer)
```

Use `some` to check existence in another Array, if not exist, push the item to new array, if exist, grab it and append the nickname.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a while a ago and this how did and you can achieve this by simply using this:

```
let result = [];

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    let id = obj.Country;

    if(!this[id]) {
        result.push(this[id] = obj);
    } else {
        this[id].Nickname += `, ${obj.Nickname}`;
    }
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

In the result you will get your desired result... and I have tested it...

Before posting the question you should try it yourself... Everyone will advice you the same... You are still new here I think but for the next time you should try first and then ask where you stuck...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to group the array into an object. Use `Object.entries` to convert the object into an array. Use `map` to format the array.

```js
var arr = [{"Country":"USA","Nickname":"John"},{"Country":"Japan","Nickname":"Grace"},{"Country":"Japan","Nickname":"Mark"},{"Country":"Japan","Nickname":"Paul"},{"Country":"China","Nickname":"Sansa"},{"Country":"USA","Nickname":"Clint"},{"Country":"China","Nickname":"James"},{"Country":"Japan","Nickname":"Mary"}];

var result = Object.entries(arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.Country] = c[v.Country] || [];
  c[v.Country].push(v.Nickname);
  return c;
}, {})).map(([k, v]) => ({"Country": k,"Nickname": v.join(' , ')}));

console.log(result);
```